# Получение прав приложения вконтакте на PHP

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте.

Я только начал разбираться с контактом и мне понадобилось на сайте вывести следующую информацию: человек вводит свой ID из vk в поле, нажимает на кнопочку и ему выводится его аватарка из vk, под ней ссылка на свою же страницу, и список его друзей (хотя бы просто фамилии). С первыми двумя пунктами разобрался, а вот с друзьями - нет (потому что не знаю, как установить права +2 (сейчас у приложения права +1).

```
<?
require 'vkapi.class.php';

$api_id     = ****; // Insert here id of your application
$secret_key = ****; // Insert here secret key of your application
$viewer_id  = ****;
$VK         = new vkapi($api_id, $secret_key);

$respo = $VK->api('getProfiles', array(
    'uids' => $viewer_id,
    'fields' => 'photo_big'
));

$id    = $respo['response'][0]['uid'];
$fot   = $respo['response'][0]['photo_big']; // переменная с сылкой
$name  = $respo['response'][0]['first_name'];
$fam   = $respo['response'][0]['last_name'];
$photo = "<img src='" . $fot . "'>";
$link  = "<a href='http://vk.com/id" . $id . "'>" . $name . " " . $fam . "</a>";
echo $photo . "<br>"; //выводим фото
echo $link . "<br>";

$resp  = $VK->api('getUserSettings', array(
    'uid' => $viewer_id
)); //посмотреть права
$resp1 = $VK->api('friends.get', array(
    'uid' => $viewer_id
)); //тут появляется ошибка 7 так как нет прав, как их получить?(

print_r($resp);
print_r($resp1);
?>
```

Приложение создавал через создание приложения, выбирал второй пункт "Веб-сайт".

Comment: @narik191, что же вам всем нравится этот класс. Напишите в конце концов уже свой и не парьтесь совершенно. API доступное и простое.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте oAuth авторизацию. Все подробно и о том, как устанавливать права.

http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2